# Что происходит, когда не успевает выполняться обработка события

Tags: java, javafx, swing

Добрый день. Вот к примеру, что если я как-то случайно нажал два раза очень быстро по какой-нибудь кнопке, так быстро, что обработка первого нажатия ещё идёт, а тут сверху ещё и второе прилетело. У меня 2 предположения.

1. Они обрабатываться вдвоём одновременно и это значит, что это два разных потока.
2. Первая обработка завершит своё выполнение и начнётся обработка второго события.

Какое утверждение верно? Если они оба ложны, сообщите правильное pls.

```
public void action(ActionEvent event) {
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
System.out.println(i);
}

{
button.addActionListener(action);
}
```

Comment: Все зависит от написанного кода. В частности в отдельном ли потоке работает swing и в отдельных ли потоках работают слушатели.

Comment: @Виктор в этом коде как дело обстоит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Swing события ставятся в очередь. Event dispatching thread выбирается события из очереди и выполняет их одно за другим. Если на момент поступления события обработчик этого события ещё занят, то события будет ожидать в очереди.

Comment: А в JavaFX наверное тоже самое, да?

Comment: [Да, только очередь используется системная.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-architecture.htm#JFXST106)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и за ссылку!